# Golang unable to create a document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to insert a document into mongoDB but I keep getting the following error despite successfully managing to connect to mongo:

```
http: panic serving 172.27.0.8:40176: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

My main.go where I'm initializing a database connection  looks like this

```
func main(){
   
      //Connect to mongo
      mongoClient,err:=connectToMongo()
      if err!=nil{
          log.Panic(err)
      }
      client=mongoClient
  
      //Create a context that mongo needs in order to disconnect
      ctx,_:=context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 15*time.Second)
     // ctx,cancel:=context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 15*time.Second)
      //defer cancel()
      
  
      //close connection
      defer func ()  {
          if err =client.Disconnect(ctx); err!=nil{
              panic(err)
          }
      }() 

    muxRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)

    //specify who's allowed to connect
    c:=cors.New(cors.Options{ 
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"https://*", "http://*"},
        AllowedMethods: []string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowedHeaders: []string{"Accept", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-CSRF-Token"},
        ExposedHeaders: []string{"Link"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        MaxAge: 300,
})
    router := AddRoutes(muxRouter)
    handler := c.Handler(router)
    log.Println("Service stratring at o  port ",webPort)

    sterr := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", handler) //Uncomment this line when using docker
    if sterr != nil {
        log.Fatal("error starting http server :: ", err)
        return
    }

    log.Println("Service started at port ",webPort)


    
  

}

func connectToMongo()(*mongo.Client,error){
    mongoUsername := os.Getenv("MONGOUSERNAME")
    mongoPassword := os.Getenv("MONGOPASSWORD")
    //create connection options
    clientOptions:=options.Client().ApplyURI(mongoURL)
    clientOptions.SetAuth(options.Credential{
        Username: mongoUsername,
        Password: mongoPassword,
    })

    //connect
    c,err:=mongo.Connect(context.TODO(),clientOptions)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Println("Error connecting to mongo",err)
        return nil,err
    }
    log.Println("Connected to mongo")
    return c,nil
}
```

In a separate file models.go is where I'm attempting to insert data into the database as follows:

```
var client *mongo.Client
func  Insert(entry LogEntry)error{
    log.Printf("Attempting to insert %s", entry)
    log.Printf("client s  %s", client)
    //db:=client.Database("logs")
    //log.Printf("database  is  %s", db)
    
   collection:=client.Database("logs").Collection("logsCollection")
    log.Printf("collection is  %s", collection)

    _,err :=collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), LogEntry{
        Name: entry.Name,
        Data: entry.Data,
        CreatedAt: time.Now(),
        UpdatedAt: time.Now(),
    })
    if err!=nil{
        log.Println("Error inserting new record into logs collection",err)
        return err
    }
    log.Println("insert successful")
    return nil
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add the full stack trace from the panic, it should show where the error is. It is likely somewhere in `handler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error is generic (e.g. the line number of the error is not provided) I'm gonna share a working solution that maybe can help you in figuring out what's wrong. Let me share the code first.

#### `main.go` file

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

type LogEntry struct {
    Name      string
    Data      string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*20)
    defer cancel()

    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017")
    mongoClient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer mongoClient.Disconnect(ctx)

    demoDb := mongoClient.Database("demodb")
    myCollection := demoDb.Collection("myCollection")

    // delete documents
    if _, err := myCollection.DeleteMany(ctx, bson.M{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // insert data
    insertRes, err := myCollection.InsertOne(ctx, LogEntry{
        Name:      "lorem ipsum",
        Data:      "lorem ipsum",
        CreatedAt: time.Now(),
        UpdatedAt: time.Now(),
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(insertRes.InsertedID)

    // query data
    cursor, err := myCollection.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var logEntries []bson.M
    if err = cursor.All(ctx, &logEntries); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, v := range logEntries {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

For the sake of the demo, I put all of the logic inside a single file. Within this file, I did the following steps:

1. Set up a MongoDB connection.
2. Connect to a database and to a collection within that database.
3. Delete all of the documents that were already there (just to be clearer).
4. Insert a new `LogEntry` instance in the `myCollection` collection.
5. Retrieve all of the entries in the `myCollection` collection.

Last thing to mention is the Docker command I used to run my container:

`docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mymongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mongo:latest`

If you stick to my solution, you should be able to insert a document without any issue. If not the case, just let me know and I'll try to help you!

Comment: Thank you. Through your solution I was able to figure out that I was not initializing var client *mongo.Client in my models.go